# extracting href attribute using xpath or cssSelector in Java

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, css-selectors

I'm trying to extract/store href attribute from following anchor tag using xpath/css expression that can be used in selenium. Could you please shed some lights.

```
<a href="http://domain/bang?a=3681fd26e8c48c2a&amp;vg=e1a15b4b-ad83-4b2b-5704-364d06783bc8&amp;pti=9&amp;pa=content&amp;hpi=775&amp;astn1=Popular&amp;rti=2&amp;u=&amp;1uguid1=19c01b00-ad83-4b2b-3832-674ce2bc1be3&amp;s=206A-0A68-603D-F35D-06C61CFAE18E&amp;pg=-1&amp;p=10215323&amp;ct=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xyz.com%2FBass-Pro-Shops-The-Hunt-Trophy-Showdown-Video-Game-for-Wii%2Fproduct%2F10215323%2F230625%3FcmCat%3DCROSSSELL_HOMEPAGE">Bass Pro Shops&reg; The Hunt Trophy...</a>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to create xpath that would allow me to store this link into some local variable in java

Comment: Is this not covered by every basic "xpath in java" tutorial? Seeing as selecting an `<a>` element is an exceedingly trivial task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Java you would do it something like this

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkPartialText("Bass Pro Shops"));
var thisLink = element.getAttribute("href");
```

to determine the CssSelector or Xpath we would need to see more code than just your anchor element.  Something with an ID would be ideal and then all the child elements of the element with the ID down to the anchor tag

Comment: this is full html for above anchor.

//div[3]/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a

Comment: Also, I'm not using webdriver. Currently using selenium grid 1

Comment: //td[@id='myid']//a@href

above xpath has helped me to get what I need. Thank you guys for chime in.